# motivation for derived categories

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, homological-algebra, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

I am studying the theory of derived categories as it is presented by [Murfet](http://therisingsea.org/). The notes are quite satisfactory and i can understand all the proofs in detail but my problem is that i can't find any reason to REALLY study derived categories because i don't know exactly the reason why they were introduced by Verdier and Grothendieck. So, briefly, my question is what problems appeared to them and what they expected to solve with derived and triangulated categories.

Comment: I can't answer the whole question, but one motivation for derived categories is "Verdier duality" for (complexes of) sheaves. For regular enough spaces the exceptional direct image functor $f_!$ may have a right adjoint $f^!$, but in general this right adjoint (the exceptional inverse image) only exists at the level of the derived category as the right adjoint of $Rf_!$, but is not itself a derived functor

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is there any reference that i can search more of what you said? Does some classical refferences include this?

Comment: I learned about it in Alexandru Dimca's book "Sheaves in Topology". This Verdier duality appears on chapter 3, but the previous two chapters are also interesting to read.